# Why I can't transfer from BTC trading wallet to my BTC wallet? using Blockchain

Tags: blockchain.info

I am trying to transfer bitcoins on Blockchain from BTC trading wallet to my BTC wallet, all I get is "insufficient funds" eventhough I have enough funds in the BTC trading wallet. Any solution?

Comment: Have you accounted for transaction fees? The sender pays the fees in Bitcoin.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure there isn't a "hold period" on your recently deposited funds. Many exchanges that do business in the USA put a 7-day "hold" on all your deposits, meaning you can trade cryptos on that exchange all you want, but until those 7 days are over, you can't withdraw anything, or transfer crypto to an outside wallet.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, make sure that you have enough funds in your trading account to cover your transfer PLUS the transaction fee, and 5hat you are not trying to transfer less BTC than whatever their "minimum transfer amount" is currently set to.